# Python sklearn confusion matrix

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn-pandas, confusion-matrix

I am trying to create a confusion matrix with probabilities.

```
y_pred_train = logistic.predict_proba(X_train)
confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred_train)

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous- 
multioutput targets
```

If I print:

```
y_pred_train[:,1]
   array([0.20189988, 0.71620557, 0.69289002, ..., 0.05712549, 0.02956872,
   0.14208470])
```

If I print:

[image]

I tried to pass just the first column of y_pred_train and still gives an error.

Why am I getting the error after the confusion matrix function? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

[`predict_proba()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba) returns the probability estimates, but you need the predicted class labels to compare them to the actual labels, so you need to use [`predict()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict) instead:

```py
y_pred_train = logistic.predict(X_train)
```